# ASP.NET MVC HttpPostedFileBase storage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC, to upload a file I simply use `<input type="file" ... />`, and the action I post the form to takes an `HttpPostedFileBase` as parameter. So far, so good. Now the question is: Does the `HttpPostedFileBase` only contain metadata and reference a temporary file on the server's disk, or does the object contain the actual bytes? This is important because of scalability, since I have a scenario where it would be very convenient to keep the `HttpPostedFileBase` in the session, but I'm afraid this might quickly fill up the server's memory if the object contains the actual bytes of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It keeps the data in memory.  If you are worried about scalability, you probably need to plan for a web farm and it wouldn't be good to have many large items in your session any how.  So probably best to manage these yourself (with files or the database and store the filename/id in the session).

The decision really depends on how many and how large the files are and what you do with them (i.e. do you need them every request, or maybe need one file in some session 20 minutes from now).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have an official source for that? Because I've been googling this desperately without any success.

Comment: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.90).aspx)  _Files are uploaded in MIME multipart/form-data format. By default, all requests, including form fields and uploaded files, larger than 256 KB are buffered to disk, rather than held in server memory._  There are ways to change the 256KB limit.  But the file is just used for buffering in any case.  it is never a complete file you can use.  You need to read the full stream and do whatever you need with it (create a file or store in memory)